# What is the probability that there will be three or more heads in a row?

Tags: probability

**You are to toss a coin five times.**

I have a few questions about this.

a) Does Three + heads in a row equate to P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5) (and thus we could solve with exactly 3 *.... * exactly 5)?

b) Is the solution 8/32?
My prof listed this but does 'in a row' change the simple answer of "counting" the # of 3 heads in 32 total combinations?

Comment: Yes, "in a row" does change the simple counting that you are considering. _Three heads in a row_ means three heads in three successive trials. So, HHHTT is OK as is THHHT, but HTHTH which _does_ have three heads but _not_ three in a row does not meet the requirements

Comment: Is the easiest way to answer this question is to list out all the outcomes of 3 heads in a row? Is there an alternative/ combinatorial proof of some sort?

Comment: Easy is relative.  If you are new to this kind of problem, then you should definitely list all 32 cases.  If you are not new, you should look for shortcuts and then check them by listing out all 32 cases.  Only after you are very certain of your reasoning should you skip the enumeration, which for some people is early and for some is never.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (a) is correct. Visualize:

$\begin{array} {c | c c c c c | c} \\
0 & T &T &T &T &T & \\
1 & H &T &T &T &T & \\
2 & T &H &T &T &T & \\
3 & H &H &T &T &T & \\
4 & T &T &H &T &T & \\
5 & H &T &H &T &T & \\
6 & T &H &H &T &T & \\
7 & H &H &H &T &T & 3 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
8 & T &T &T &H &T & \\
9 & H &T &T &H &T & \\
10 & T &H &T &H &T & \\
11 & H &H &T &H &T & \\
12 & T &T &H &H &T & \\
13 & H &T &H &H &T & \\
14 & T &H &H &H &T & 3 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
15 & H &H &H &H &T & 4 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
16 & T &T &T &T &H & \\
17 & H &T &T &T &H & \\
18 & T &H &T &T &H & \\
19 & H &H &T &T &H & \\
20 & T &T &H &T &H & \\
21 & H &T &H &T &H & \\
22 & T &H &H &T &H & \\
23 & H &H &H &T &H & 3 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
24 & T &T &T &H &H & \\
25 & H &T &T &H &H & \\
26 & T &H &T &H &H & \\
27 & H &H &T &H &H & \\
28 & T &T &H &H &H & 3 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
29 & H &T &H &H &H & 3 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
30 & T &H &H &H &H & 4 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
31 & H &H &H &H &H & 5 \text{ heads in a row }  \\
\end{array}$

So the answer is $\frac 8 {32}$, which is the sum of the cases where there are exactly 3 in a row, exactly 4 in a row, and exactly 5 in a row.

For part (b), notice how if you didn't specify "in a row", then we would also have to count rows 11, 13, 19, etc.  So $\frac {5 \choose 3} {32} $ would overcount solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Three heads in a row occur for the first time in position 123 or 234 or 345. Case 123 corresponds to the set of sequences HHH?? which has probability 1/8. Case 234 corresponds to the set of sequences  THHH? which has probability 1/16. Case 345 corresponds to the set of sequences  ?THHH which has probability 1/16. These cases are disjoint hence three heads in a row occur with probability 1/8+1/16+1/16=1/4.